# For random variables, show that $\limsup\limits_nX_n<\infty\Longrightarrow \sup_n X_n<\infty$

Tags: proof-verification, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

> Why is the following true ?
>
> $$\limsup\limits_nX_n<\infty\Longrightarrow \sup_n X_n<\infty$$
>
> where, $X_n's$ are random variables.

If we consider only finitely many $X_n$, say $n\in\{1,...,m\}$ then every $X_n$ must have a finite output, since they're random variables, so if we also have $\limsup\limits_nX_n<\infty$, then $X_n$ is finite for all $n$. Is that true ?

Thanks.

EDIT: here is link, where I encountered this problem ($4$th line of the solution).

http://f.666kb.com/i/cr9yzgvnmlryuswod.gif

Comment: This is only true if the index is bounded below - if $n\in\mathbb Z$, for example, it is not true. But if it is a sequence $X_0,X_1,\dots$ then it is true.

Comment: Is $X_i$ allowed to be infinite? If so, that's a bit confusing. Unbounded would be allowed. But $\limsup x_i$ can be finite when $x_1=+\infty$, so your statement is not correct. And even if $x_i$ is finite for each $i$, that doesn't mean $\sup x_i$ is finite for each $x_i$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews but random variables are real-valued or not ?

Comment: Well, you say it is a random variable, which usually means real-valued or complex-valued, and not infinity, but you also say: "...then $X_n$ is finite for all $n$," which implies you think $X_n$ can take $+\infty$ as a value. Basically, your question is confused.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=\limsup X_n$, then there are only finitely many $i$ such that $X_i<Y+1$.

Specifically, let $Y=\limsup X_n$. Let $N$ be the random variable which is the largest $N$ such that $X_i\geq Y+1$, or $N=0$. Then $\sup X_n <\max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N,y+1)$.

(As mentioned above, this assumes that the indexes $i$ of $X_i$ are bounded below and integers. If we are dealing with $\dots,X_{-2},X_{-1},X_0,X_1,\dots$, then this is not true. I assume above that the sequence starts $X_1$.)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I mean natural numbers with $n$. Actually it is a part of an exercise, and it is assumed that $\limsup\limits_nX_n<\infty$ $\text{a.s.}\Longrightarrow \sup_n X_n<\infty$ $\text{a.s.}$, but does it change anything ?

Comment: That is certainly if and only true if, for each $n$, $X_n<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is true in general. $\limsup_n X_n<\infty$ means that $\sup_{k\geq n} X_k$ will converge (and decrease down) to  finite number when $n$ large. So this says nothing about $X_n$ for small $n$, some of which may misbehave.

Comment: Unless $X_i$ can be $\infty$, some misbehaving can't make $\sup X_n=\infty$.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews: the problem in the shaded box doesn't say otherwise so there is a possibility of that.

Comment: "Random variable" almost always assumes a real-valued, occasionally complex values. Don't play games. The $X_i$ can be unbounded, and the above statement is still true.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews: I'm not playing games. I genuinely thought the question permitted that possiblity. The OP will see our comments here and decide for himself/ herself. Cheers.